# Maven archetype not substituting properties for module directory name

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I created an archetype of a multi-module project, and my intention is to substitute required property `__implementation__` for directory names.  The result is, `__rootArtifactId__` was substituted, but the `__impelementation__` was not.

*archetype-metadata.xml:*

```
<module id="${rootArtifactId}-${implementation}-impl" dir="__rootArtifactId__-__implementation__-impl" name="${rootArtifactId}-${implementation}-impl">
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true" encoding="UTF-8">
      <directory>src/main/java</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.java</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
      <directory></directory>
      <includes>
        <include>pom.xml</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</module>
```

*properties:*

```
artifactId=basic
implementation=foo
```

*resulting directory:* `basic-__implementationName__-impl`

The substitutions happen just fine in: pom.xml and *.java, but have problems with directories

Is there a way to make archetype use properties for directory names?

Comment: It looks like this is related to [ARCHETYPE-455](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-455)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem I did the following:

1. cloned maven-archetype source code through git

   ```
   git clone --branch maven-archetype-2.4 https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/maven-archetype.git
   ```
2. Performed the modification mentioned here [ARCHETYPE-455](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-455)
3. Performed maven install on the maven-archetype project (some unit tests do not work)

   ```
   mvn install -DskipTests
   ```

Afterwards, directory names are correctly replaced.

Comment: Added pull-requests to maven-archetype:https://github.com/apache/maven-archetype/pull/13